# How do I calculate the sqrt in MathNet.Symbolics

Tags: mathnet-numerics, math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

I'm using the `MathNet.Symbolics` library to simplyfy expressions like this :

```
string f = Infix.Print(Infix.ParseOrThrow("A+5*2"))
```

This works as expected (`f = A+10`) but trying to get the root of a number is a lot harder than I expected. For example :

```
string f = Infix.Print(Infix.ParseOrThrow("sqrt(9)"))
```

`f = "sqrt(9)`" instead of `f = "3"` as you would expect.

```
string f = Infix.Print(Infix.ParseOrThrow("sqrt(x^2)"))
```

`f = "sqrt(x^2)"` insted of `f = "x"`

```
string f = Infix.Print(Infix.ParseOrThrow("9^(1/2)"))
```

also doesn't work. Insted it gets simplified to `f = "sqrt(9)"`

How do I force it to calculate the sqrt of a number/variable?

Are there any other problems I could expect to run into when using the "auto-simplification" of `MathNet.Symbolics`?

Comment: See also: https://discuss.mathdotnet.com/t/how-do-i-calculate-the-sqrt-in-math-net-symbolics/533

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the expression through the `Evaluate` method:

```
string f = Infix.Print(Infix.ParseOrThrow("sqrt(9)"));
double result = Evaluate.Evaluate(null, f);
```